# Poor disk IO on Redhat VM on Hyper-V 2012 R2

Tags: linux, virtualization, redhat, hyper-v, io

We recently migrated a RedHat 5.11 virtual machine from an alternative provider (VMWare) to ourselves (HyperV).

The machine boots and is online etc, but the IO sucks compared to pre-migration...

[output of sar - Pre-migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xucUR.png)

[output of sar - Post-migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD21b.png)

This translates to users experiencing timeouts in apache and general poor performance of the machine.

I have disabled Virtual Machine Queues on the physical adapters on this hypervisor and on the virtual NIC's of the machine.
I have also ensured that 'elevator=noop' is in the grub.conf, but neither of these things seem to made a difference at all.

Has anyone seen this before or can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: i am not faimilliar with hyperv,still do you have the corresponding drivers enabled in the vm.
probably look at /proc/modules

Comment: Do you know if you used emulated or paravirtualized IO drivers before? And what about now?

Comment: Indeed... I added the linux intergration components for HyperV and disabled the VMWare tools.

Comment: emulated or paravirtualized IO drivers.... not sure on either.
I remember the older versions of HyperV gave this as an option, but as far as I'm aware it is no longer an option.